# Sony headphone doesn't allow input + output

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones, sony

Ubuntu 18.04, Sony WH-H900N

In sound settings, I can set the input device to the headphone `Headset - WH-H900N(H.ear)`, but whenever i do that, it automatically sets the output quality to `Headset Head Unit(HSP/HFP)` instead of `High Fidelity Playback(A2DP Sink)`. When I set it to `A2DP sink`, it switches the input to the built-in microphone again.

I have tried installing `bluez-5.52`, but it didn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Please ask for more info if you need more

Update: recently upgraded 20.04 Focal Fossa, the problem still persists.

I would say it's a hardware limitation where the bandwidth isn't enough, but it works with both mic and sound on my phone(iPhone 6), so clearly it isn't.